# common lisp invoking function without apply leads to odd number of keywords

Tags: arguments, common-lisp, apply, function-call, parameter-list

i am currently learning common lisp and stumbled upon a question i could not
answer my self:

```
(defun find-all (item seq &rest keyword-args &key (test #'eql)
                     test-not &allow-other-keys)
 (if test-not
   (apply #'remove item seq
          :test-not (complement test-not) keyword-args)
   (apply #'remove item seq
          :test (complement test) keyword-args)))
```

The function is used to find every element in seq matching item according
to a test function.
Sadly I dont understand why the function 'apply' was used here.
Shouldn't it be possible to just invoke remove without apply?
A warnings says: "The function has an odd number of arguments in the keyword portion" if I invoke remove without apply.

I hope you can help me,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**REMOVE and FIND-ALL**

`REMOVE` takes a bunch of keyword arguments: from-end, test, test-not, start, end, count and key.

Now in the function `FIND-ALL` you want to modify just one: either *test* or *test-not* and then call `REMOVE`.

**How to write the parameter list of FIND-ALL**

Now you have basically three options to write the parameter list of `FIND-ALL`, since it is basically the same as `REMOVE` with only one argument changed.

1. list every keyword argument with their defaults and later pass them on with the necessary changed to `REMOVE`.
2. list only a *rest arguments* list, manipulate this argument list and pass the new one via `APPLY` to `REMOVE`.
3. mix of 1. and 2. like in the example above. List only the required arguments and the keyword arguments to modify plus a rest list of the other keyword arguments provided at call time. Call `REMOVE` via `APPLY`.

**How good are the three possibilities?**

Now 1. has the advantage that you get to see a full parameter list for `FIND-ALL` and that it does not need to cons an argument list. Lisp can check some of that. But you really need to copy all arguments in your parameter list and later in the calls to `REMOVE`. Possible but not that great.

Then 2. has the disadvantage of not having a visible parameter list for `FIND-ALL`, but it might be easier to write with a few functions to manipulate argument lists. 3. is relatively easy to write, but also lacks the full parameter list.

**Your example**

Thus in your example it is version 3 of above:

- the required arguments are passed in first
- next are the modified arguments
- last is the list of all keyword arguments

If you want to pass an existing list of arguments as part of the arguments to the function, then you need `APPLY`. That's why it is used there. `APPLY` calls a function with the arguments taken from a list.

```
CL-USER 1 > (apply #'+ 1 2 '(3 4 5))
15

CL-USER 2 > (let ((numbers '(3 4 5)))
              (apply #'+ 1 2 numbers))
15


CL-USER 3 > (+ 1 2 3 4 5)
15
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's take for example the signature of [`REMOVE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm):

```
remove item sequence &key from-end test test-not start end count key 
=> result-sequence
```

The above means the function accepts 2 mandatory arguments, `item` and `sequence`, and additional keywords arguments that should be given with the `:key value` syntax. If you only give the key or the value, like:

```
(remove x list :count)
```

Then it is invalid. A simple test is to look at the number of parameters in *keyword position* and check that the number of given arguments is even. When it is odd, you know something is wrong.

If you call:

```
(remove item seq args)
```

You are in the same case. It does not matter that `args` is a list in your specific case.

#### Apply

[`APPLY`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm) is a more generic way of calling a function: its last argument is a *list of additional arguments*.

Suppose `args` is bound to `(3 4)`, then:

```
(apply #'+ 1 args)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(+ 1 3 4)
```

This works with keyword arguments too; if `args` is the list `(:count 1)`, then:

```
(apply #'remove item seq args)
```

is equivalent to:

```
(remove item seq :count 1)
```

And here, the number of arguments in keyword position is even.